# Is SharePoint online a good platform for CRUD applications with requirements for documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, web-application

Is SharePoint online a good platform for CRUD applications with requirements for documents ?

I have experience with on premises SharePoint, so storing documents wasn't not a problem at slightest but I haven't worked much with SharePoint online.

For a web application to be used by 10-50 people to add job requests (could be a simple SharePoint list)and change there status, and for each request they will upload documents maybe from 0 to 100MB but most files will be less then 20MB.

Would SharePoint online be a good candidate for such application or should I consider non SharePoint applications ?

**Edit**

The thing I forgot to add and what concerns me most to ask this question is that does Microsoft charges for document storage on Office 365, couple of years ago looking at different planes I couldn't figure this out.

Specially when using SharePoint hosted apps (not sure if they still exist)

Not necesarry but if you could tell me which model in SP online suits best for this app please ? many thanks

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint looks like great candidate, just make sure you are preparing application for SharePoint Online Thresholds, cause you cannot change them here.

- You can find lots of documentation, [one is here.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)
- Storage thresholds are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits). (Based on licences)

Comment: +1, sorry I forgot to mention what concerns me most to use SharePoint online as a platform, does Microsoft limits amount of storage you can have per tenant ? I edited my question, thank you much

Comment: Hello, added another MS post.

Answer (score 1):

Given the requirements you've described above, SharePoint online seems like it would be a good fit. There's certainly nothing in your requirements that stands out as outside of the boundaries and limits of SharePoint online.

And if you're familiar with on premises, it's not so very different, except if you need custom code, it will have to be done either client-side or remotely (which may or may not have been true on premises).